# How to Create Multiple tables in SQLite in programatically way ie; by code in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_taxOrganizerDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      char *errMsg;
      const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ADDRESS TEXT,PHONE NO INT)";

      if (sqlite3_exec(_taxOrganizerDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
      {

      }

      sqlite3_close(_taxOrganizerDB);

    } else 
    {
    }
}
```

I want to create multiple tables in sqlite browser ,for single application.

Comment: So you are asking how to execute another CREATE TABLE statement? (And why do you have a column `PHONE` with the type `NO INT`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put multiple statements on your string

```
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DATA TEXT);" //TEST
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (USER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PASSWORD TEXT, TYPE TEXT);" //USER
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS METADATA (METADATA_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VERSION TEXT)"; //METADATA


            if (sqlite3_exec(_database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create tables");
            }
            sqlite3_close(_database);
            NSLog(@"DataBase created at: %@",_databasePath);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your create table statement is the way to create a table, however column names cannot have spaces. Change your "Phone No" to "Phone_No" and it should work. Also, you don't need autoincrement. Any column declared as integer primary key will autoincrement automatically.